# STM32 hex file, determine if it needs a custom bootloader

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

it is possible to determine somehow if a hex file (that I know is compiled/intended to work on a STM32F405) can be flashed to a blank STM32F405 chip, or if this hex is just a "firmware update" that needs a custom bootloader to run on, hence can only be flashed on a chip that already has that particular bootloader in it?

I could just try to flash it on a blank chip, but at the moment I don't have a STM32F405 prototype board so if possible I'd like to understand that before building a PCB for this task.

this is the start of the hex file (posted as suggested in the comment below)

```
:020000040800F2
:10000000F8F40120690200089528000897280008E4
:100010009B2800089F280008A32800080000000073
:10002000000000000000000000000000A9280008F7
:10003000A728000800000000AB280008AD28000831
:10004000830200088302000883020008830200087C
:100050008302000883020008DD280008EF2800085A
:100060000129000813290008252900088302000837
:10007000830200088302000883020008CD280008DC
:10008000830200088302000883020008830200083C
:100090008302000883020008830200083729000851
:1000A000830200088302000883020008830200081C
:1000B000830200088302000883020008830200080C
:1000C00083020008830200088302000883020008FC
:1000D000C5280008D528000883020008830200080C
:1000E00089290008830200088302000883020008AF
:1000F00083020008830200088302000883020008CC
:1001000083020008B5280008830200088302000863
:1001100083020008830200088302000883020008AB
:10012000830200088302000883020008BD2800083B
:10013000830200088302000883020008830200088B
```

Comment: If the start address of the hex file is 08000000 (or 0) then it probably can stand alone.  If it isn't, then it can't.  If you don't know how to read the address from the file then you could edit the question to include the first few lines of the file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question with the start of the hex file

Comment: That looks like it could be programmed straight in. But... it is using 16-bit addresses (can address 64KB) whereas your MCU seems to have 1MB of flash. So who knows. If you suspect maybe a bootloader is involved, maybe this _is_ the bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel HEX format is explained in depth for example on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX).

Let's start the analysis with the first record.

`:020000040800F2`: The record type is '04', designating an extended linear address. The data field contains the upper 16 bits of the 32 bit address, '0800'. Citing the Wikipedia page:

> The absolute address for a type `00` record is formed by combining the upper 16 address bits of the most recent `04` record with the low 16 address bits of the `00` record.

Therefore, the following code bytes are located at 0x0800xxxx, xxxx being the addresses of the data records. According to the data sheet, this is the first 64 KiB page of the flash. The first following data record has the address 0x0000, resulting in the absolute address 0x08000000.

The regular pattern of the following bytes looks like a vector table.

*Side note: Please be aware that the records in a Intel HEX file don't need to be in order.*

If your hex file is larger than about 130 KiB (two times 64 KiB because of two hex characters per byte), we can expect another extended linear address record with '0801', and so on.

Depending on your boot configuration, we can assume that this code needs no specific bootloader to run.

Comment: Therefore, the following code bytes are located at 0x0800xxxx. it has to be 0x08000000. Otherwise, it needs the bootloader.

Comment: @0___________ Since there is more than the first byte @ 0x08000000, I used that form. It depends on the addresses in the data records, the analysis of which I leave to you. ;-) Anyway, extended a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Hex format goes way back, it's older than me, from the 1900s. I was on the side of intel in the Intel/Motorola wars, but I like srecord better, but only because of the s3 type...

```
:02 000004 0800F2

:10 0000 00 F8F40120 69020008 95280008 97280008 E4
:10 0010 00 9B280008 9F280008 A3280008 00000000 73
:10 0020 00 00000000 00000000 00000000 A9280008 F7
:10 0030 00 A7280008 00000000 AB280008 AD280008 31
:10 0040 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 83020008 7C
:10 0050 00 83020008 83020008 DD280008 EF280008 5A
:10 0060 00 01290008 13290008 25290008 83020008 37
:10 0070 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 CD280008 DC
:10 0080 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 83020008 3C
:10 0090 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 37290008 51
:10 00A0 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 83020008 1C
:10 00B0 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 83020008 0C
:10 00C0 00 83020008 83020008 83020008 83020008 FC
:10 00D0 00 C5280008 D5280008 83020008 83020008 0C

:10 000000 
F8F40120
69020008
95280008
97280008
E4


0x2001F8F4 stack pointer init
0x08000269 reset
0x08002895 some other vector
...
```

Someone is using some complicated builder, perhaps one from ST.  But so far all valid the vectors are in the 0x08000000 address space although they do not have to be.  It does have to have the lsbit set to indicate it is thumb code, otherwise you hard fault.

the cortex ms can have up to hundreds of vectors, for performance reasons, and at least the snippet you posted (it is a snippet not the whole thing yes?)  those are all exception and interrupt handler vectors some of them are zeros, so whomever did this did not point them at an infinite loop, but whatever.  So this does very much look vector table, you could go look at 0x08000268 and see if you see something that looks like instructions, which you can disassemble if you want. (I'll let you figure that out, it's variable length instructions so you will eventually confuse the tool).

In no way does this mean that simply flashing it on the part won't crash it or even let smoke out.  You are on your own, not my fault, not our fault.  Particularly with language like

> before building a PCB for this task.